# Using expect script to do an ssh from a remote machine

Tags: ssh, expect

I am new to expect scripts and have a use case in which I need to do an ssh from a machine in which I have already done an ssh using expect script. This is my code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 60
spawn ssh username@machine1.domain.com

expect "Password: "
send "Password\r"

send "\r" # This is successful. I am able to login successfully to the first machine

set timeout 60
spawn ssh username@machine2.domain.com  #This fails
```

This takes a some amount of time and fails saying 
ssh: connect to host machine2.domain.com port 22: Operation timed out. I understand that 22 is the default port on which ssh runs and I can manually override it by giving a -p option to ssh.

If I try to ssh independently without the expect script I get a prompt that asks me to enter (yes/no). From where is the correct port being picked up if I execute ssh directly without the expect script. If I do not need to enter the port number on shell why would it be needed to enter a port number if I am using an expect script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That that point, you don't spawn a new ssh: spawn creates a new process on your local machine. You just send a command to the remote server

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 60
spawn ssh username@machine1.domain.com

expect "Password: "
send "Password\r"

send "\r" # This is successful. I am able to login successfully to the first machine

# at this point, carry on scripting the first ssh session:
send "ssh username@machine2.domain.com\r"
expect ...
```

Comment: It took me a good night sleep to understand what I was mucking up. You had answered before I could make that change in my script. Just modified the second attempt to ssh to a send instead of spawn and it worked. Thanks.