# Script for logging in as user and executing another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to run a set of commands after logging into a remote machine -

```
sudo su - weblogic
Enter password
sh /pathtofile.sh
```

The following approach doesnt do anything. It logs me into the server as weblogic but then does nothing. When I press Ctrl + C, it then executes sh/pathtofile.sh

```
ssh -t user@host 'sudo su - weblogic; sh /pathtofile.sh'
```

I have searched everywhere I could, but however I cannot find the right solution to this. Please help!

Comment: This may help http://superuser.com/questions/243499/automating-the-sudo-su-user-command

Comment: You could use [expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226563/using-expect-script-to-do-an-ssh-from-a-remote-machine) for this task.

Answer (score -1):

The test failed for the **SUID** or **setuid** for a script because on linux it is disable by default for script.

To use SUID you might want to create an binary executable which in turn starts the final script. SUID should work with binaries.

**-- for reference --**

Normal users on the system who have permission to execute this file gain the privileges of the user who owns the file.

```
sudo chown weblogic /pathtofile.sh
sudo chmod 4755 ./pathtofile.sh
```

Comment: Note that suid bit does not work for scripts - this won't work

Comment: I used to see SUID working for script. Am I wrong?
Maybe on some old UNIX. I could not remember which ones: Reliant-UNIX ? Solaris 6 - 7 ?

Comment: This may have worked on some really old Unix systems. But this is considered security hole, and does not work on any modern Unix, including Linux.

Comment: This will not work for me. I have set the right ownership and permissions for the file. The situation here is such that it does not execute anything after executing sudo su - weblogic.