# How to use telnet in a script?

Tags: bash, scripting, telnet

I need to connect in a system where I have to SSH first then telnet. Then I can start executing some command.
I am struggling about the telnet part. Can you tell me how I can make it please? Is there another alternative than spawn please? Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
cat command.sh | sshpass -p 'passowrd' ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@pc1;
```

Then my command.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
spawn telnet pc_modem
expect "login:"
send "root"
expect "Password:"
send "youyou"

cliclient GetMonitoringData;
```

Comment: This looks like `expect` script, not `bash`.

Comment: even If change #!usr/bin/expect -f   ... not working as well .... "spawn command not found "   "expect command not found"  "send command not found".... but I did the install.. I am quite lost :(

Comment: The places where spawn, etc. are installed probably are missing from your PATH env. variable. Maybe they got installed in /opt, or /usr/local/bin. Also: does for instance 'spawn' work from the command-line?

Comment: Here's an example of what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226563/using-expect-script-to-do-an-ssh-from-a-remote-machine

Comment: Perhaps you are unable to avoid `telnet`. If you can though, you should.

Comment: @Roadowl I checked /opt /usr/local/bin there is nothing, expect is located at /usr/bin and nothing is happening if I just enter spawn.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I have two option... either I use curl command to execute what I need but it's not working... or I use telnet and get easier command to execute but struggling to connect....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the answer and works perfectly :

```
/bin/expect <<<'spawn telnet pc_modem 
expect "login:"
send "root\r"
expect "Password: ";
send "youyou\r"

send "yourcommand1\r"
send "yourcommand2\r"

expect eof
'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this use, the shebang has no effect*. You're passing the contents of the script file to ssh to be executed line by line as if each line were separate commands that will be interpreted by the shell instead of `expect`.

Try changing `command.sh` to something like:

```sh
# no shebang here
/bin/expect -f - <<<'spawn telnet pc_modem
expect "login:"
send "root"
expect "Password:"
send "youyou"

cliclient GetMonitoringData;'
```

This sends the `expect` script as a *here string* to expect's STDIN. If you use variables in your `expect` script you may need to change the quoting or escaping depending on whether they are shell or TCL variables and where the substitution needs to take place.

* The shebang is used by the kernel to select the program to interpret the contents of the file when the file has been marked as executable and is run by invoking the file by its name. When a file is run by explicitly naming the interpreter (e.g. `sh run_me` or `ssh user@host run_me_there`) the shebang doesn't come in to play.

Comment: Hi @Dennis, thank you so much for your answer!!!! it's very helpful, it doesn't return the same error as before, I removed -f ... so far it does the telnet but now the struggle is with the password... it doesn't enter the password....