# Programmatically interact with ssh prompt from bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bash script which launches an SSH process with `-R 0:someServer:1234` argument to bind a port using an auto-selected port (hence the `0` in the argument). When that is done, SSH prints out the auto-selected port. Then, I manually type in the `~C` SSH escape sequence to enter the SSH prompt where I can further type `-L 9876:localhost:<auto-selected-port>` which forwards the port to my localhost.

This works great, but requires manual interaction. I was wondering if there is a way to automate this manual operation in bash.

Comment: Use an `Expect` script.

Comment: This might be useful: [Using expect script to do an ssh from a remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226563/4154375).

Comment: Alas, I think what I am trying to do cannot be done because the script runs on the remote machine, but ~C needs to be interpreted on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example using my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) —

##### The script (`ssh-LR.sh`):

```bash
export SEXPECT_SOCKFILE=~/tmp/ssh-LR-$$.sock
mkdir -p ~/tmp

remote=foo@myserver
passwd='foobar'
ps1_re='bash-[.0-9]+[$#] $'
R_port=
L_port=54321

sexpect spawn -t 20 ssh -t -R 0:someserver:12345 $remote bash --norc
sexpect expect -i 'password: ' || exit
sexpect send -cr "$passwd"

sexpect expect -re 'Allocated port ([0-9]+) for remote forward' || exit
R_port=$( sexpect out -i 1 )
sexpect expect -re "$ps1_re" || exit

sexpect send -cr "~C"
sexpect expect 'ssh> ' || exit
sexpect send -cr -- "-L $L_port:localhost:$R_port"
sexpect expect 'Forwarding port' || exit

sexpect send -cr
sexpect expect -re "$ps1_re" || exit
sexpect interact
```

##### Run it:

```
$ bash ssh-LR.sh
foo@10.0.1.74's password:
Allocated port 44465 for remote forward to someserver:12345
bash-5.2$
ssh> -L 54321:localhost:44465
Forwarding port.

bash-5.2$
bash-5.2$                # <-- now it's in interactive mode
```